# C# string padding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I'm writing a WPF application on C# which has a ListBox in it. The list box has an item on each row in the following format:

```
ID Name     Price
```

I know that the ID has the maximum of 3 numbers, the minimum of one and the name is less than 25 characters so I want to align those 3 values in columns, something like this:

```
194 Item Name 1          24.99
1   Item Other Name       4.00
13  Item Item Item       32.22
```

And so on...
I'm tried couple of things:

```
string.Format("{0} {1} {2:0.00}", id.ToString().PadRight(4), name.PadRight(25), price)
```

The other option I tried:

```
string.Format("{0, -4} {1, -25} {2:0.00}", id, name, price)
```

Unfortunately every time I get an ID of 3 numbers it pushes the text a little bit further to the right so the columns are not aligned. Any tips or ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Why are you not using a DataGrid?

Comment: You should expose `ID`, `Name` and `Price` as public properties in an item class, then bind your ListBox to a collection of these items and use an appropriate data template for display. See the [Data templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `WPF` you have the option to have multiple `Textblocks` in a `StackPanel` that is inside of the `DataTemplate` of the `Listbox`'s `ItemTemplate`. **@Clemens** has a great link for this. You can also set the StackPanels `Orientation` to `Horizontal` so all are on one line. This way you can set the `TextAlignment` to `Right` or `Left`. If the StackPanel does not work well you can also use a Grid and set `GridColumns` and place the `Textblocks` to a specific Column.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to WPF so those were some very useful tips!